# C# WPF cef Access Violation on changing the text of my textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I hope you can help me. I try to code a litle browser using cef.

The problem is, I get a access violation while changing the Text of a TextBox at public void browser_FrameLoadEnd

```
public partial class Internet : Page
{
    string Url;      

    public Internet()
    {
        InitializeComponent();             
    }

    private void surf_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        browser.Load(uri.Text);                             
    }    

    public void browser_FrameLoadEnd(object sender, CefSharp.FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
    {
        uri.Text = Url;
    }     

    private void browser_FrameLoadStart(object sender, CefSharp.FrameLoadStartEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Url = e.Url;          
    }
}
```

please help me. Why it will not work ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the event arrives in a different thread. Hence you have to call the `Invoke` method of the `TextBox`, e.g.

```
uri.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => uri.Text = Url));
```